# How to trace function calls in Marionette

Tags: javascript, debugging, marionette

Somewhere in the global scope:

```
let App =  Backbone.Marionette.Application.extend({});
window.Ext = new App();
```

Inside Module A:

```
Ext.vent.trigger('Tracked:Email:send', {
    from_email: tracking_data.sender,
    to_emails: tracking_data.to,
    cc_emails: tracking_data.cc,
    email_id: tracking_data.email_id || '',
    template: tracking_data.template_id || '',
    subject: tracking_data.subject
});
```

Inside Module B:

```
Ext.vent.on('all', function (evt_name, params) {
    // something else...
    console.log(params);
}
```

The object's properties (`from_email`, `to_emails` & `cc_emails`) are `undefined` when I call console.log in Module B.

I've tried to debug this using `console.trace`, but the console doesn't show any functions that are involved in changing the object. I've also tried using `Object.observe` to capture the act of changing the object but no changes are detected.

Can some please teach me some debugging techniques to trace function calls and events in Marionette.

The scenario is:

1. our codebase is huge.
2. I'm a new guy at our company so I'm not sure if there are other functions or events that are involved.
3. I'm the only front end developer right now.

Comment: Sounds like you are just having a hard time understanding what is going on in the codebase. How about just putting a breakpoint when you trigger the event and walk through the code while watching that object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news: there's nothing special about Marionette here. Everyday JavaScript debugging techniques will help you out.

The bad news: as you're aware, debugging large, event-driven applications is *difficult*.

You could take these steps in Chrome dev tools (YMMV with other browsers):

1. Split the `App.trigger` line to get a reference to the parameters object:

```
let options = { from_email: ... }
App.vent.trigger('Tracked:Email:send', options);
```

2. [Set a breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/breakpoints/add-breakpoints?hl=en) on `Ext.vent.trigger` and run your code.

   When execution pauses at the breakpoint, check that `options` contains the expected values. If not, the problem is somewhere before `App.vent.trigger`. Look up the [call stack](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#call-stack-panel) for any functions that affect `tracking_data`. You may need to check the *Async* checkbox if it is populated by asynchronous code.

   If `options` contains the values you expect, carry on...
3. Whilst execution is paused use the console to save a global reference to your parameters object:

```
> OPTIONS = options
```

4. Add `OPTIONS` as a [watch expression](https://remysharp.com/2013/11/27/using-watches-in-my-devtools-workflow). Expand the item so you can watch changes to its properties.
5. Step through (including Marionette and Backbone code) until you see the `OPTIONS` properties change. If you don't see Marionette code when you step into `App.vent.trigger` you may need to remove Marionette from your [black boxed libraries](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#blackboxing).

Comment: I've traced the issue, it seems that the backend guys changed the properties of tracking_data. That is why tracking_data.sender, tracking_data.to & tracking_data.cc are undefined. I should have seen this from the start, silly me. But anyway, thanks for teaching me a debugging technique this will help me in the future. This is my first job so it is kinda tough.

Comment: And there you've learned the most important debugging tool of all - [Occam's razor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor): Try the simplest explanation first :-)